# error when i start my customtkinter program

Tags: python, tkinter, customtkinter

```
from CTkListbox import CTkListbox
from PIL import Image
import tkinter as tk
import customtkinter
import json
import os,time
from newclient import newclient

n = 0
path = "C:/Users/gaeri/Downloads/mamanprod/Nouveau dossier"
current_file_path = ""
current_username = json.load(open(f"C:/Users/{os.getlogin()}/AppData/Local/Temp/user_gg/user.json", "r"))['current_username']

files = [os.path.join(path, file) for file in os.listdir(path) if file.endswith('.json')]

def check_login():
    session_name = entry_session_name.get()
    session_password = entry_session_password.get()
    f = open("C:/Users/gaeri/Downloads/mamanprod/users.json")
    content = json.load(f)
    f.close()
    if os.path.exists(f"C:/Users/{os.getlogin()}/AppData/Local/Temp/user_gg/user.json") == False:
        open(f"C:/Users/{os.getlogin()}/AppData/Local/Temp/user_gg/user.json", "x")
    try:
        if content[session_name] == session_password:
            g = open(f"C:/Users/{os.getlogin()}/AppData/Local/Temp/user_gg/user.json")
            content = json.load(g)
            g.close()
            if content['current_username'] != session_name:
                content['current_username'] = session_name
                with open(f"C:/Users/{os.getlogin()}/AppData/Local/Temp/user_gg/user.json", "w") as g:
                    json.dump(content, g, indent = 2)
                g.close()
            login.destroy()
        else:
            entry_session_name.configure(placeholder_text = "Mot de pass incorect")
            entry_session_name.delete(0, tk.END)
    except:
        entry_session_name.configure(placeholder_text = "Nom incorect")
        entry_session_name.delete(0, tk.END)

def new_client():
    save_content()
    app.destroy()

    app.mainloop()

def log_out():
    g = open(f"C:/Users/{os.getlogin()}/AppData/Local/Temp/user_gg/user.json")
    content = json.load(g)
    content['current_username'] = ""
    with open(f"C:/Users/{os.getlogin()}/AppData/Local/Temp/user_gg/user.json", "w") as g:
        json.dump(content, g, indent = 2)
    app.destroy()

def show_content(selected_option):
    global current_file_path
    selected_option = listbox.curselection()
    current_file_path = files[selected_option]
    try:
        f = open(current_file_path)
    except: pass
    content = json.load(f)
    
    label_client_name_message = f"{content['name']}"
    label_client_name.configure(text = label_client_name_message)

    text_client_notes_message = f"{content['notes']}"
    text_client_notes.delete(0.0, "end")
    text_client_notes.insert(0.0, text_client_notes_message)

    text_client_infos_message = f"Mail : \n{content['contact']['mail']}\nPhone : \n{content['contact']['phone']}\nFacture : \n{content['bill']}"
    text_client_infos.delete(0.0, "end")
    text_client_infos.insert(0.0, text_client_infos_message)

    label_client_infos_phone_message = f"{content['phone']}"
    label_client_infos_phone.configure(text = label_client_infos_phone_message)

    last_edited.configure(text = f"Derniere modification par {content['last_edit']}")

def search_file(event):
    searched = search.get()
    listbox.delete(0, tk.END)
    for file in files:
        if searched.lower() in file.lower():
            listbox.insert(tk.END, os.path.basename(file)[:-5])

def save_content(event = True):
    global current_file_path
    if current_file_path == "":
        return
    f = open(current_file_path)
    content = json.load(f)
    edited_content_client_infos = text_client_infos.get(1.0, tk.END)
    content['contact']['mail'] = str(edited_content_client_infos.splitlines()[1])
    content['contact']['phone'] = str(edited_content_client_infos.splitlines()[3])
    content['bill'] = str(edited_content_client_infos.splitlines()[5])
    edited_content_client_notes = text_client_notes.get(1.0, tk.END)
    content['notes'] = str('\n'.join(edited_content_client_notes.splitlines()))
    content['last_edit'] = current_username
    with open(current_file_path, 'w') as f:
        json.dump(content, f, indent = 2)

def new_client_save():
    if os.path.exists(path + "/" +entry_name.get() + ".json") == False:
        open(path + "/" +entry_name.get() + ".json", "x")
    content = {"name": "","notes": "","phone": "","bill": "","contact": {"phone": "","mail": ""},"last_edit": ""}
    content['name'] = entry_name.get()
    content['phone'] = entry_phone.get()
    content['bill'] = entry_bill.get()
    content['contact']['phone'] = entry_phone_number.get()
    content['contact']['mail'] = entry_mail.get()
    with open(path + "/" +entry_name.get() + ".json", "w") as f:
        json.dump(content, f, indent = 2)
        f.close()
    newclient.destroy()

#MAIN

app = customtkinter.CTk(fg_color = "#F4F5F7")
app.title("T-Rex managment")
customtkinter.set_appearance_mode("light")
customtkinter.set_default_color_theme("C:/Users/gaeri/Downloads/mamanprod/theme.json")
app.geometry("1080x700")
app.resizable(False, False)

font = customtkinter.CTkFont(family="Rubik", size = 20, weight = "bold")
font2 = customtkinter.CTkFont(family="Rubik", size = 15, weight = "normal")
font3 = customtkinter.CTkFont(family="Rubik", size = 15, weight = "bold")
font4 = customtkinter.CTkFont(family="Rubik", size = 40, weight = "bold")

#Upper-Left corner

image_new_client = customtkinter.CTkImage(Image.open("C:/Users/gaeri/Downloads/mamanprod/assets/frame0/button_1.png"), size=(60, 60))
button_new_client = customtkinter.CTkButton(app, command = new_client, image = image_new_client, text = "", width = 60, height = 60)
button_new_client.place(x = 20, y = 17)

image_new_client_2 = customtkinter.CTkImage(Image.open("C:/Users/gaeri/Downloads/mamanprod/assets/frame0/image_111.png"), size=(176, 61))
button_new_client_2 = customtkinter.CTkButton(app, command = new_client, image = image_new_client_2, text = "", width = 176, height = 61)
button_new_client_2.place(x = 82, y = 17)

image_magnifying_glass = customtkinter.CTkImage(Image.open("C:/Users/gaeri/Downloads/mamanprod/assets/frame0/button_3.png"), size=(60, 60))
button_magnifying_glass = customtkinter.CTkButton(app, command = search_file, image = image_magnifying_glass, text = "", width = 60, height = 60)
button_magnifying_glass.place(x = 20, y = 100)

image_search = customtkinter.CTkImage(light_image = Image.open("C:/Users/gaeri/Downloads/mamanprod/assets/frame0/entry_1.png"), size = (176 , 61))
label_search = customtkinter.CTkLabel(app, image = image_search, text = "", width = 176, height = 61)
label_search.place(x = 86, y = 104)

search = customtkinter.CTkEntry(app, placeholder_text = "Nom du client", font = font, fg_color = "#F0F0F3", bg_color = "#F0F0F3", text_color = "#728AB7", width = 160, height = 40)
search.bind("<KeyRelease>", command = search_file)
search.place(x = 97, y = 115)

image_searched = customtkinter.CTkImage(light_image = Image.open("C:/Users/gaeri/Downloads/mamanprod/assets/frame0/image_4.png"), size=(237 , 237))
label_searched = customtkinter.CTkLabel(app, image = image_searched, text = "")
label_searched.place(x = 286, y = 104)

listbox = CTkListbox(app, command = show_content, font = font2, text_color = "#728AB7", fg_color = "#F0F0F3", border_width = 0, border_color = "#F0F0F3", corner_radius = 10, width = 205, height = 213)
listbox.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", lambda event: show_content)
listbox.place(x = 288, y = 109)

for file in files:
    file_name = os.path.basename(file)[:-5]
    listbox.insert(tk.END, file_name)

#Bottom-Left corner

label_common_infos = customtkinter.CTkLabel(app, font = font3, text = "Information communes", text_color = "#898989", fg_color = "transparent", width = 180, height = 15)
label_common_infos.place(x = 28, y = 360)

image_common_infos = customtkinter.CTkImage(light_image = Image.open("C:/Users/gaeri/Downloads/mamanprod/assets/frame0/image_3.png"), size=(495, 278))
label_common_infos = customtkinter.CTkLabel(app, image = image_common_infos, text = "")
label_common_infos.place(x = 28, y = 382)

text_common_infos = customtkinter.CTkTextbox(app, font = font, text_color = "#484848", fg_color = "#F0F0F3",undo = True, width = 480, height = 262)
text_common_infos.bind("<Control-s>", save_content)
text_common_infos.place(x = 34, y = 390)

#Upper-Right corner

image_login = customtkinter.CTkImage(light_image = Image.open("C:/Users/gaeri/Downloads/mamanprod/assets/frame0/image_1.png"), size=(176, 61))
label_login = customtkinter.CTkLabel(app, image = image_login, text = "")
label_login.place(x = 875, y = 21)

image_logout = customtkinter.CTkImage(light_image = Image.open("C:/Users/gaeri/Downloads/mamanprod/assets/frame0/button_4.png"), size=(30, 30))
button_logout = customtkinter.CTkButton(app, image = image_logout,command = log_out, text = "", bg_color = "#F0F0F3", hover_color = "#F0F0F3", width = 30, height = 30)
button_logout.place(x = 888, y = 33)

label_username = customtkinter.CTkLabel(app, font = font3, text = current_username, text_color = "#728AB7", fg_color = "#F0F0F3", width = 100, height = 40)
label_username.place(x = 930, y = 32)

image_client_name = customtkinter.CTkImage(light_image = Image.open("C:/Users/gaeri/Downloads/mamanprod/assets/frame0/entry_1.png"), size=(176 , 61))
label_client_name = customtkinter.CTkLabel(app, image = image_client_name, text = "")
label_client_name.place(x = 570, y = 105)

label_client_name = customtkinter.CTkLabel(app, font = font, text = "", text_color = "#728AB7", fg_color = "#F0F0F3", width = 160, height = 40)
label_client_name.place(x = 580, y = 115)

image_save = customtkinter.CTkImage(Image.open("C:/Users/gaeri/Downloads/mamanprod/assets/frame0/image_save.png"), size=(176 , 61))
button_save = customtkinter.CTkButton(app, command = save_content, image = image_save, text = "", width = 176, height = 61)
button_save.place(x = 872, y = 100)

image_client_infos = customtkinter.CTkImage(light_image = Image.open("C:/Users/gaeri/Downloads/mamanprod/assets/frame0/image_7.png"), size=(473, 165))
label_client_infos = customtkinter.CTkLabel(app, image = image_client_infos, text = "")
label_client_infos.place(x = 575, y = 177)

image_client_infos = customtkinter.CTkImage(light_image = Image.open("C:/Users/gaeri/Downloads/mamanprod/assets/frame0/image_2.png"), size=(106, 153))
label_client_infos = customtkinter.CTkLabel(app, image = image_client_infos, text = "")
label_client_infos.place(x = 935, y = 183)

text_client_infos = customtkinter.CTkTextbox(app, font = font, text_color = "#484848", fg_color = "#F4F5F7", undo = True, width = 350, height = 155)
text_client_infos.bind("<Control-s>", save_content)
text_client_infos.place(x = 579, y = 180)

image_client_infos_phone_logo = customtkinter.CTkImage(light_image = Image.open("C:/Users/gaeri/Downloads/mamanprod/assets/frame0/phone.png"), size=(50, 50))
label_client_infos_phone_logo = customtkinter.CTkLabel(app, image = image_client_infos_phone_logo, text = "", bg_color = "#F0F0F3")
label_client_infos_phone_logo.place(x = 965, y = 202)

label_client_infos_phone = customtkinter.CTkLabel(app, font = font4, text = "", text_color = "#484848", fg_color = "#F0F0F3", width = 60, height = 50)
label_client_infos_phone.place(x = 960, y = 267)

#Bottom-Right corner

label_client_notes = customtkinter.CTkLabel(app, font = font3, text = "Notes du client", text_color = "#898989", fg_color = "transparent", width = 180, height = 15)
label_client_notes.place(x = 545, y = 360)

image_client_notes = customtkinter.CTkImage(light_image = Image.open("C:/Users/gaeri/Downloads/mamanprod/assets/frame0/image_5.png"), size=(481, 278))
label_client_notes = customtkinter.CTkLabel(app, image = image_client_notes, text = "")
label_client_notes.place(x = 572, y = 382)

text_client_notes = customtkinter.CTkTextbox(app, font = font, text_color = "#484848", fg_color = "#F0F0F3", undo = True, width = 466, height = 262)
text_client_notes.bind("<Control-s>", save_content)
text_client_notes.place(x = 576, y = 390)

last_edited = customtkinter.CTkLabel(app, font = font3, text = "", text_color = "#484848", fg_color = "#F4F5F7", width = 180, height = 15)
last_edited.place(x = 580, y = 660)

#LOGIN

login = customtkinter.CTkToplevel(fg_color = "#F4F5F7")
login.title("T-Rex managment | connection")
customtkinter.set_appearance_mode("light")
customtkinter.set_default_color_theme("C:/Users/gaeri/Downloads/mamanprod/theme.json")
login.geometry("300x200")
login.resizable(False, False)

font = customtkinter.CTkFont(family="Rubik", size = 20, weight = "bold")
font2 = customtkinter.CTkFont(family="Rubik", size = 15, weight = "normal")
font3 = customtkinter.CTkFont(family="Rubik", size = 15, weight = "bold")
font4 = customtkinter.CTkFont(family="Rubik", size = 40, weight = "bold")
font5 = customtkinter.CTkFont(family="Rubik", size = 14, weight = "bold")

session_name = customtkinter.CTkLabel(login, font = font3, text = "Nom", text_color = "#898989", fg_color = "#F4F5F7", width = 40, height = 40)
session_name.place(x = 30, y = 0)

image_session_name = customtkinter.CTkImage(light_image = Image.open("C:/Users/gaeri/Downloads/mamanprod/assets/frame0/login_box.png"), size = (258 , 61))
label_session_name = customtkinter.CTkLabel(login, image = image_session_name, text = "", width = 258, height = 61)
label_session_name.place(x = 20, y = 30)

entry_session_name = customtkinter.CTkEntry(login, placeholder_text = "Carole SAILL", font = font, bg_color = "#F0F0F3", text_color = "#323232", placeholder_text_color = "#BDBDC0", width = 245, height = 40)
entry_session_name.place(x = 25, y = 41)

session_password = customtkinter.CTkLabel(login, font = font3, text = "Mot de pass", text_color = "#898989", fg_color = "#F4F5F7", width = 90, height = 40)
session_password.place(x = 32, y = 90)

image_session_password = customtkinter.CTkImage(light_image = Image.open("C:/Users/gaeri/Downloads/mamanprod/assets/frame0/password_box.png"), size = (193 , 61))
label_session_password = customtkinter.CTkLabel(login, image = image_session_password, text = "", width = 170, height = 61)
label_session_password.place(x = 22, y = 120)

entry_session_password = customtkinter.CTkEntry(login, font = font, bg_color = "#F0F0F3", text_color = "#323232", width = 183, height = 40)
entry_session_password.place(x = 27, y = 131)

image_login = customtkinter.CTkImage(light_image = Image.open("C:/Users/gaeri/Downloads/mamanprod/assets/frame0/login_checkbox.png"), size = (60 , 60))
button_login = customtkinter.CTkButton(login, image = image_login, text = "", command = check_login, width = 60, height = 60)
button_login.place(x = 212, y = 116)

#NEWCLIENT

newclient = customtkinter.CTkFrame(fg_color = "#F4F5F7")
newclient.title("T-Rex managment | nouveau client")
customtkinter.set_appearance_mode("light")
customtkinter.set_default_color_theme("C:/Users/gaeri/Downloads/mamanprod/theme.json")
newclient.geometry("700x400")
newclient.resizable(False, False)

#1st range

image_namee = customtkinter.CTkImage(light_image = Image.open("C:/Users/gaeri/Downloads/mamanprod/assets/frame0/entry_1 - Copie (3) - Copie.png"), size=(176 , 60))
label_namee = customtkinter.CTkLabel(newclient, image = image_namee, text = "", width = 176, height = 60)
label_namee.place(x = 15, y = 10)

entry_name = customtkinter.CTkEntry(newclient, placeholder_text = "Nom", font = font3, bg_color = "#F0F0F3", text_color = "#323232", placeholder_text_color = "#BDBDC0", width = 166, height = 40)
entry_name.place(x = 20, y = 21)

image_phone_number = customtkinter.CTkImage(light_image = Image.open("C:/Users/gaeri/Downloads/mamanprod/assets/frame0/entry_1 - Copie.png"), size=(176 , 60))
label_phone_number = customtkinter.CTkLabel(newclient, image = image_phone_number, text = "")
label_phone_number.place(x = 15, y = 80)

entry_phone_number = customtkinter.CTkEntry(newclient, placeholder_text = "Numero de telephone", font = font3, bg_color = "#F0F0F3", text_color = "#323232", placeholder_text_color = "#BDBDC0", width = 166, height = 40)
entry_phone_number.place(x = 20, y = 91)

image_phone = customtkinter.CTkImage(light_image = Image.open("C:/Users/gaeri/Downloads/mamanprod/assets/frame0/entry_1 - Copie (2) - Copie.png"), size=(176 , 60))
label_phone = customtkinter.CTkLabel(newclient, image = image_phone, text = "")
label_phone.place(x = 15, y = 150)

entry_phone = customtkinter.CTkEntry(newclient, placeholder_text = "Nombre de telephones", font = font3, bg_color = "#F0F0F3", text_color = "#323232", placeholder_text_color = "#BDBDC0", width = 166, height = 40)
entry_phone.place(x = 20, y = 161)

#2nd range

image_bill = customtkinter.CTkImage(light_image = Image.open("C:/Users/gaeri/Downloads/mamanprod/assets/frame0/entry_1 - Copie (3).png"), size=(176 , 60))
label_bill = customtkinter.CTkLabel(newclient, image = image_bill, text = "")
label_bill.place(x = 200, y = 10)

entry_bill = customtkinter.CTkEntry(newclient, placeholder_text = "Montant de la facture", font = font3, bg_color = "#F0F0F3", text_color = "#323232", placeholder_text_color = "#BDBDC0", width = 166, height = 40)
entry_bill.place(x = 205, y = 21)

image_mail = customtkinter.CTkImage(light_image = Image.open("C:/Users/gaeri/Downloads/mamanprod/assets/frame0/entry_1 - Copie (4).png"), size=(176 , 60))
label_mail = customtkinter.CTkLabel(newclient, image = image_mail, text = "")
label_mail.place(x = 200, y = 80)

entry_mail = customtkinter.CTkEntry(newclient, placeholder_text = "Adresse mail", font = font3, bg_color = "#F0F0F3", text_color = "#323232", placeholder_text_color = "#BDBDC0", width = 166, height = 40)
entry_mail.place(x = 205, y = 91)

image_valid = customtkinter.CTkImage(light_image = Image.open("C:/Users/gaeri/Downloads/mamanprod/assets/frame0/image_long_checkbox.png"), size = (177 , 60))
button_valid = customtkinter.CTkButton(newclient, image = image_valid, text = "",command = new_client_save, width = 60, height = 60)
button_valid.place(x = 197, y = 146)


g = open(f"C:/Users/{os.getlogin()}/AppData/Local/Temp/user_gg/user.json")
content = json.load(g)
g.close()
if content['current_username'] != "":
    app.mainloop()
else:
    login.mainloop()
```

here is my code

When I start the program, it tells me an error but sometimes, it works and it is very uncomfortable. Please help!

```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\gaeri\Downloads\mamanprod\main.py", line 135, in <module>
    button_new_client = customtkinter.CTkButton(app, command = new_client, image = image_new_client, text = "", width = 60, height = 60)
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\gaeri\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\customtkinter\windows\widgets\ctk_button.py", line 106, in __init__
    self._draw()
  File "C:\Users\gaeri\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\customtkinter\windows\widgets\ctk_button.py", line 264, in _draw
    self._update_image()  # set image
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\gaeri\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\customtkinter\windows\widgets\ctk_button.py", line 173, in _update_image
    self._image_label.configure(image=self._image.create_scaled_photo_image(self._get_widget_scaling(),
  File "C:\Users\gaeri\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1721, in configure
    return self._configure('configure', cnf, kw)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\gaeri\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1711, in _configure
    self.tk.call(_flatten((self._w, cmd)) + self._options(cnf))
_tkinter.TclError: image "pyimage7" doesn't exist
```

Normally, the script start and shows a login title if not logged. After that, it will display the main window and finally, if you click on the 1st button, it will pop a new window where you can create a new json file.

[UPDATE]

Just splited the code in differents fonctions, use toplevel and works again.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).